# Vertical align: middle is slightly off at the top

Tags: html, css

I've recently started to learn CSS, and I've come across something I just can't figure out.
http://jsfiddle.net/HDKsq/7/ is my fiddle. 
I'm trying to set the buttons in my navbar to be aligned perfectly in the middle vertically. The buttons are elements in an unordered list, and I've set them to vertical-align:middle; but the space on top of the buttons is visibly larger than the bottom, am I using the wrong syntax?

```
ul li{
list-style:none;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 2px solid white;
padding-right : 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
background-color:black;
border-radius:6px;
line-height:100%;
text-align:center;
width: 150px;
```

for clarification this is what I'm asking about
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
padding: 10px 10px;
```

to

```
padding: 6px 10px 10px;
```

To center the `li`s, you'll have to manually adjust the padding. This has to do with the height of the picture you have for the home logo. If that remains at 30px, then you need to adjust because it's affecting the height of the `li`s, which have a line-height of 100% (meaning the text will adjust to the height of the picture). Therefore, depending on the size of the picture used, you'll need to specify the `padding-top`, since the picture will flow downwards (it's larger than the size it should be to center).

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/Nv22G/1/)

Please forgive my use of a placeholder kitten. I hope you don't break out into tears of joy.

Comment: Thank you! this fixed it. One more question, when the CSS aligns a picture, does it align based on the middle of the picture or the bottom of the picture?

Comment: @lonewaft This [website](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/) has a really good writeup on `vertical-align`. Do note that `vertical-align` only works on `inline` or `block` elements and, as you have applied it to the links, not the images, it will center based on that element (the link). Since the image is larger than the `<li><a>…</a></li>` parent(s), it will overflow downwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfect man, just because of small 'g' in Google you feel it like it's touching to the bottom border.

This is because the character formation of 'g', you will get same effect for 'q'.

Your CSS is perfect.

Comment: I wish haha, but I think I was unclear with which margin I was talking about sorry, clarified in the post with an image now.